# Long exact sequence of homotopy groups $\pi_n$ for a pointed homotopy pullback square

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

Let
\begin{align}
A &\to B\\
\downarrow &~~~~~\downarrow\\
C &\to D
\end{align}
be a homotopy pullback square of *pointed* simplicial sets. One gets a long exact sequence
$$
\cdots\to\pi_n(A)\to \pi_n(B)\times \pi_n(C)\to \pi_n(D)\to \cdots\to\pi_0(A)\to \pi_0(B)\times \pi_0(C)
$$
of homotopy groups as the homotopy pullback square defines a homotopy fiber sequence $\Omega D\to A\to B\times C$.

> Does this sequence extend to the right by $\cdots\to \pi_0(D)$ or even by $\cdots\to \pi_0(D)\to 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't -- in fact, there's not even a natural map!  For instance, consider the case that $B=C=D=\mathrm{pt}_+$, with all maps the identity.  The map in positive degrees uses the group structure on $\pi_{\geq 1}(D)$ in a crucial way.